# How can I solve $A\operatorname{diag}(x)=B\;?$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, inverse, pseudoinverse, inverse-problems

How can I solve $A\operatorname{diag}(x)=B\;?$

I am actually an engineer and recently involved in this field.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Just take row 1 of $A$ and $B$ and figure out $X$ from there.

Comment: If you just look at the 2X2 case, $x_1 = b_{11}/a_{11}$ and $x_1 = b_{21}/a_{21}$, $x_2 = b_{22}/a_{22}$ and $x_2 = b_{12}/a_{12}$, and that generalizes easily to NXN.  So isn't there a solution only if all of those equalities hold?

Comment: This equation is suspect. Where does it come from ?

Comment: Actually I am looking for X in A*diag(B*X)=C with this constrain(Xi>0) .and  A is not square matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following answer uses a convention in which uppercase latin denotes a matrix, lowercase latin a vector, and greek a scalar.

Define ${\rm diag}()$ as a function which returns the main diagonal of its matrix argument as a column vector, and ${\rm Diag}()$ as a function which create a diagonal matrix from a vector argument.

Denote 
the elementwise/Hadamard product using a $\odot$ symbol

and the trace/Frobenius product using a colon, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$

In the current problem, define the matrix variables
$$\eqalign{
X &= {\rm Diag}(x) \\
E &= AX-B \\
}$$
Minimize the norm of $E$ (the error matrix) by 
formulating a cost function and calculating the point where 
its gradient equals zero.

$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \tfrac{1}{2}\|E\|^2 = \tfrac{1}{2}E:E \\
d\phi &= E:dE = E:A\,dX = A^TE:dX \\
 &= A^TE:{\rm Diag}(dx) \\
 &= {\rm diag}\Big(A^T\big(AX-B\big)\Big):dx \\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}
 &= {\rm diag}(A^TAX) - {\rm diag}(A^TB) \\
}$$
Set the gradient to zero and solve for the optimal $x$.
$$\eqalign{
{\rm diag}(A^TB) &= {\rm diag}(A^TAX) \\
 &= \left(I\odot A^TA\right)x \\ 
x &= (I\odot A^TA)^{-1}\operatorname{diag}\left(A^TB\right) \\
}$$
This vector is the least-squares solution to the problem.

Comment: thanks for your response. would you please tell me how can you derive diag(AT(AX−B)):dx from the above equation? is A:B equal to diag(A):diag(B) ?

Comment: It helps to think of the Frobenius product as the sum over all the elements of the Hadamard product, e.g. $$M:P=\sum_i\sum_j (M\odot P)_{ij}$$ Now if $P$ happens to be a diagonal matrix, i.e. $\,{\rm Diag}(p),\,$ then the off-diagonal elements of $M$ can be ignored since they are being multiplied by **zeros** in the Hadamard product. So you only need the main diagonal of the matrix, which can be interpreted as a _vector_. Therefore the relevant identity is $$M:{\rm Diag}(p)={\rm diag}(M):p$$

Comment: thanks for your comprehensive response. it really helps me. one more thing relevant to this topic which is questionable for me is if we have W=A*Diag(B*c), how can we calculate ∂w/∂c? B is matrix and c is vector.

Comment: Near the end of my derivation, we have the differential relationship 
$$d\phi = v:dx$$
Now you're saying that you forgot to tell me that $x=Bc$.
$$ $$But that's okay, since I can calculate $dx\;$ **in terms of** $\;dc$
$$dx = B\,dc$$
substitute it, and solve for the gradient wrt $c$
$$\eqalign{
d\phi &= v:B\,dc = B^Tv:dc \\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial c} &= B^Tv \\
}$$

Comment: thanks a lot. your responses really helped me. but the last question is how about the situation that we have constraint on our optimization?  for example lb<c<ub which means that all elements of c should be between a lowerband and an upperband.

Comment: Set any $x_k$ components which are below/above the lower/upper bound to the bound.

Comment: Hello again, thanks for your helpful advice. now suppose I have :
$$\eqalign{
{\rm diag}(A^TB) &= {\rm diag}(A^TAXB)}$$ \\
how can I find x?

Comment: @HadiEsfandi $$\eqalign{
{\rm diag}(A^TAXB) = \left(B^T\odot A^TA\right)x \\
}$$

Comment: Hello again. would you please take a look at this question? Thanks
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3702895/constraint-matrix-least-square-optimization

Answer (score 0):

We consider element at position $(i, j)$ of the matrix that is the LHS,

$$ [A\, \text{diag}(x)]_{ij} = \sum_{z=1}^d A_{iz} [\text{diag}(x)]_{zj}
$$
As 
$$[\text{diag}(x)]_{ji} = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
x_i & i = j \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.
$$
then
$$
[A\, \text{diag}(x)]_{ij} = A_{ij} x_{j}
$$
So we have for all $(i,j)$
$$
A_{ij} x_{j} = B_{ij}
$$
whether this is possible satisfy depends.

Comment: Actually I am looking for X in A*diag(BX)=C with this constrain(Xi>0) .and A is not square matrix
A is n'-by-m
B is m-by-n 
x is n-by-1