# matrix least square optimization with constraint

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

I want to Minimize the following equation (the error matrix) by 
formulating a cost function and calculating the point where 
its gradient equals zero. 
\begin{equation}
    \hat{X} = \arg \min_{X} \frac{1}{2} {\left\| AX - B \right\|}_{F}^{2} 
\end{equation}
where  $$X= {\rm Diag}(x)$$ 
I did this optimization problem without constraint: 
$$\eqalign{
E &= AX-B\\
\phi &= \tfrac{1}{2}\|E\|^2 = \tfrac{1}{2}E:E \\
d\phi &= E:dE = E:A\,dX = A^TE:dX \\
 &= A^TE:{\rm Diag}(dx) \\
 &= {\rm diag}\Big(A^T\big(AX-B\big)\Big):dx \\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}
 &= {\rm diag}(A^TAX) - {\rm diag}(A^TB) \\
}$$
Set the gradient to zero and solve for the optimal $x$.
$$\eqalign{
{\rm diag}(A^TB) &= {\rm diag}(A^TAX) \\
 &= \left(I\odot A^TA\right)x \\ 
x &= (I\odot A^TA)^{-1}\operatorname{diag}\left(A^TB\right) \\
}$$

now, I want to minimize above optimization problem with constraint:\begin{equation}
    \hat{X} = \arg \min_{X} \frac{1}{2} {\left\| AX - B \right\|}_{F}^{2} , X= {\rm Diag}(x)
\end{equation}
\begin{align}
\text{subject to } & x_{i}^{min} \leq x_{i} \leq x_{i}^{max} \\ 
\end{align}
I recently learnt about Lagrange multipliers but I'm not sure how to apply that to my problem. I'll appreciate if any one can help me how to apply that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_i$ and $b_i$ be the $i$th columns of $A$ and $B$, respectively. Let $\tilde A$ be the block diagonal matrix whose $i$th diagonal block is $a_i$, and let $b$ be the column vector obtained by vertically concatenating the vectors $b_i$. Notice that 
$$\| AX - B \|_F^2 = \| \tilde A x - b \|_2^2.
$$ So your optimization problem is
\begin{align}
\text{minimize} & \quad \frac12 \| \tilde A x - b \|_2^2 \\
\text{subject to} & \quad c \leq x \leq d
\end{align}
where $c$ is the vector whose $i$th component is $x_i^\min$ and $d$ is the vector whose $i$th component is $x_i^\max$. The optimization variable is $x$. Projecting onto the constraint set is easy, so you could solve this problem using the projected gradient method or an accelerated projected gradient method. (Other methods such as interior point methods are also possible.)

When implementing the projected gradient method, it will help to know that the gradient of your objective function
$$
f(x) = \frac12 \| \tilde A x - b \|_2^2
$$
is
$$
\nabla f(x) = \tilde A^T(\tilde A x - b).
$$

Comment: thanks. suppose in a simple case A,B are 3-by-4 matrices. So, based on your definition $\tilde A$ becomes 12-by-12 matrix and b will be 12-by-1 vector. the original $x$ is 4-by-1 but the solution given by your approach  will be 12-by-1 vector. there are two cases. 1: original solution( without constraints)  is within our limits ,in this case  $x$ is just repeated  3 times and we can easily extract 4-by-1 $x$ from 12-by-1 vector. in case 2 original solution is out of range $c \leq x \leq d$ . here the  $x$  given by your approach is not repeated. How we can find original $x$? Tnx

Comment: @MahshadJavidan No, if $A$ and $B$ are $3 \times 4$ matrices then $\tilde A$ is $12 \times 4$. In detail, $\tilde A = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 & & & \\ & a_2 & & \\ & & a_3 & \\ & & & a_4 \end{bmatrix}$. Here each $a_i$ is a $3 \times 1$ column vector.